# wordpress dropdown-pages on customizer

Tags: wordpress, frontend

i'm using dropdown-pages on the customizer section to select and link to a page.
So far so good.

But I also need to echo the name of the selected page in the front-end.
I only have success echoing the page Id.
Is it possible to get the page name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the page name with $pagename. However if that isn't available, try this:

```
global $post;
$pagename = $post->post_name;
echo 'page name: ' . $pagename;
```

If the front page is static, you'll have to query the name:

```
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
```